# Yahoo accounts in Linked Inbox no longer work

Tags: settings, email

Everytime I open my linked inbox, it asks me to update my account info and that my passwords are incorrect.  Each time I know I am entering the correct password because I can log into yahoo in IE.  This is a recent problem.  Could some settings on yahoo's end need changing?  It only happens to my yahoo accounts.